# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android, android-studio

no entiendo porque salen estos errores vi en google que era porque tenia código arriba del `setContentView()` pero quite todo el código de ese archivo java y solo deje el diseño y aun así no me cierra la aplicación.

Quite el diseño y así si corre la aplicación.

Mi Logcat:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías añadir tu clase por favor. en lo posible como texto

Comment: Luis, acostumbra agregar el código y el mensaje en el LogCat como texto para que sea visible,saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tratas de cargar un recurso como imagen que en realidad no es imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En tu layout estas cargando un botón que a su vez trata de cargar una imagen, pero **el problema es que este recurso llamado "goo" que se encuentra dentro del folder `/drawable` no es en realidad una imagen.**